# openlayers vector layer annihilating browser

Tags: openlayers, vector

I am trying to render a layer with polygons so that I can utilise the snap-to feature in openlayers.
This layer has got a lot of data, I had assumed utilising the strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox would limit what it is trying load but it seems strange that at 1:4K it needs to download 78meg before assassinating my browser tab.

Any tips on getting this to work?

```
new ol.layer.Vector({
            title: 'topo',
            visible: true,
            renderMode: 'image',
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                url: function(extent) {
                    return "site.com?typeName=my:layer&service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=application%2Fjson";
                },
                params: {layers: "my:layer"},
                strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
                crossOrigin: "Anonymous"
            }),
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#f00',
                    width: 1
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
                })
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not enough to define the loading strategy, you also have to include the current extent to the url. So, append the following code to the url:

```
'&bbox=' + extent.join() + ',EPSG:3857'
```

(or whatever EPSG/SRID you use)

Comment: Brilliant thank you.
It's getting a limited set of features now, just not displaying anything on the map - but that is a separate issue.

Cheers!